# Currency CultureInfo

Tags: c#

I need to display currency in a culture specific way we are currently supporting only english speaking countires but that might expand to another countries. We are implementing this quickly so I need a way of displaying a universal currency format for the time being until I can implement a culture specific.

Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

The Executing Thread has a CultureInfo attribute attached to it for example "en-GB" which is "English-Great Britain" or "cy-GB", for "Welsh- Great Britian"(The First 2 characters represent the language the Second 2 the country). So when you are calling

```
double amount = 2.00;
amount.ToString("C")//Without a culture argument you are 
                    //actually passing the CultureInfo
```

So to add specific CultureInfo to a string all you have to do is supply a new CultureInfo and add it as a second argument in ToString like so:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
amount.ToString("C", ci);
```

Add the following line to the Web.config to change it application wide

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
```

OR the Following line if you would like it as a Per Page Basis

```
<%@ Page UICulture="en" Culture="en-GB" %>
```

OR Change the Culture on the Executing Thread

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

The international way of display currency is (U+00A4)(As Referenced CLR Via C# as I haven't seen it anywhere else) which can be displayed using .`ToString("C", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` which displays a little star thing which I dont think anyone will recognize.

Also, please remember that none of this is getting around the currency conversion problem, unless everything that needs to be displayed converts straight across to another currency value for value. You would be better off just display in US dollars Or UK Pounds until you can work out the best way to localize your application.

Comment: Unfortunately this way couples the currency symbol with the number format. The number format should be correct for the language the content is in, while the currency symbol needs to be the correct one for the currency being talked about.

Comment: You are only passing in cultureinfo for that specific string for that specific instance when using ToString

Comment: how  to  apply  culture  through out  my  WIndows  phone  application...  please  help...